# How can I support 2 subdomains in the same route

Tags: symfony, routes

I want to setup one of my web apps so it can be accessed using 2 different subdomains. (This is so I can spit the traffic in my DNS records and for pre release testing)

The 2 urls I want to handle are admin.mydomain.com and admin1.mydomain.com

This is what I have in app/config/routing.yml

```
incompass_admin:
    host:     "{sub}.mydomain.com"
    resource: "@MyAdminBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"
    defaults:
        sub: admin
    requirements:
        sub: admin|admin1
```

That only partially works. Once I have logged in to admin1.mydomain.com, all the generated links go to admin.mydomain.com

So, wherever I have used {{ path('my_route_name') }} in twig, I get a link to the default subdomain, instead of the subdomain I used.

If I manually edit the url, I can get to all the admin1.mydomain.com pages.

How can I get symfony to use the subdomain that was originally entered as the url?

Comment: Are you sure that you not hardcoded/setup redirection url when user log in?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the router will generate relative URLs:

```
{{ path('foo') }} //output '/foo'
```

You don't need worry about the host domain/subdomain unless you have other router resource with the same `path`.

If you use `{{ url('foo') }}` the host that's used when generating an absolute URL is automatically detected using the current Request object. So, neither you need use Placeholders.

> See more about [Using Placeholders](http://symfony.com/doc/current/routing/hostname_pattern.html#using-placeholders) use cases.

To do that your routing definition would be enough with:

```
 incompass_admin:
     resource: "@MyAdminBundle/Resources/config/routes.yml"
```